# Javascript fetch flask json

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, create-react-app

So I'm trying to connect a Flask server to a front end create react app. Right now I just want to verify that I can send json between the two. Below is the code for each and a bit more description on the errors.

Create React App fetch

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      pyResp: []
    }
  }

 fetchHelloWorld() {
    console.log("fetching python localhost");
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode:'no-cors',
      dataType: 'json'
    })
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(r => {
        console.log(r)
        this.setState({
          pyResp: r
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Blockchain Voter</h1>
        <p>
          {this.state.pyResp}
        </p>
        <button onClick={() => this.fetchHelloWorld()}>Python</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Flask Server

```
from flask import *
from json import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    jsonResp = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139}
    print(jsonify(jsonResp))
    return jsonify(jsonResp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I get this error (in the chrome console) -

> Unexpected end of input(…)

I can see the json in the Networks tab in Chrome, it just seems to be erroring on the parsing.

Stuck on whether this is a flask syntax error (i.e. not sending it correctly), a javascript parsing error (i.e. I'm making some simple mistake I can't see), or a create react app bug that I don't understand.

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: @AlexHall The error is in the chrome console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You most likely do not have CORS enabled in your Flask application. CORS stands for Cross Origin Resource Sharing which allows python webapps to say OK we share with  or browser or whatever. Anyway the solution should be something like this.

In the terminal/bash `$ pip install -U flask-cors`

In your app

```
from flask import *
from json import *
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    jsonResp = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139}
    print(jsonify(jsonResp))
    return jsonify(jsonResp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Awesome, this works. I hadn't delved too deep into cors yet but your explanation is helpful for a beginning understanding!

Comment: Please select best answer and let me know if you would like additional help

Comment: I had to remove `mode:'no-cors'` in the js file to get it to work