# React javascript fetch python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, react-native, flask

So I'm trying to connect a Flask server to a front end create react app.  Below is the code for each and a bit more description on the errors. I followed the existed answer [from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915319/javascript-fetch-flask-json)

Create React App fetch

```
export default class Toggle extends Component {

    state = {
        on: false,
        pyResp: []
    }

    toggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            on: !this.state.on,
        })

        console.log("fetching python localhost");
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(r => {
                console.log(r)
                this.setState({
                    pyResp: r
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="toggle">
                    <div className="toggle-btn"><button onClick={this.toggle}> Toggle </button> </div>
                    <div className={!this.state.on ? "display-txt hide" : "display-txt show"}>
                        {this.state.on && <p>true</p>}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="text-box"> <label> Name:<input type="text" name="name" /> </label></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And Flask Server

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    jsonResp = {"jack": 4098, "sape": 4139}
    print("===print===")
    print(jsonify(jsonResp))
    return jsonify(jsonResp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**I am getting error
Toggle.js:27 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Toggle.js:16**

Comment: Sara - May I know what's in line 16 of Toggle.js? And is the error from line 16 or line 27? If it's 27, let know that line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be here

```
<div className={!this.state.on ? "display-txt hide" : "display-txt show"}>
    {this.state.on && <p>true</p>}
</div>
```

Change to

```
<div className={!this.state.on ? "display-txt hide" : "display-txt show"}>
    {(this.state.on) ? (<p>true</p>) : null) }
</div>
```

Comment: Same error even after the new changes, i think issue is not related to front end. the error is on fetch api line  " SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Toggle.js:16 "

Comment: Try remove dataType: 'json' from fetch

Answer (score 0):

Change the mode from `no-cors` to `cors`.

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors'
        })
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(r => {
                console.log(r)
                this.setState({
                    pyResp: r
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I tried locally and this worked for me.

Comment: Also, remove the `dataType: 'json'`. It's not required.

Comment: @Sara - Thank you. If it works, kindly mark it as the right answer and upvote.